# Route port forward through 2 windows server 2008R2 network adapters to another network

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, routing, ip, port-forwarding

our phone system at work is on a separate network to everything else and I need to forward a port from our gateway to it to allow our phone tech to remotely administer it. I have plugged the phone network into a spare network adapter on our server which I've setup on the phone's network and can access the phone administration page through.

If I create a port forward to the server's network adapter on the PC network how do I route this to an address on the second adapter's network?

Comment: Why not let your router do this? That's what it's made for.

Comment: No spare ports on the router...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a goofy solution and even if you get it working, it's sloppy. You may already even have a layer-3 switch that could do the job of routing for you if you just enable that functionality.

That said, you need to enable IP routing (sometimes called IP forwarding) on the server. [Nice walkthrough at wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-IP-Routing). Then make sure you have a route to access the phone network on the other side of the server (e.g., the Internet router, firewall, etc).

Comment: It would be a lot better if you included the actual relevant steps in addition to linking to the article/

Comment: So your contribution is to complain that I didn't hand-hold carefully enough? Next time save your keystrokes.

Comment: No - my coontribution is to point out that if you read the FAQ here on providing good answers (http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) it specifically states "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline". If I was complaining, I would have downvoted your answer. As a new user, I was trying to help you to be a better citizen of this site.

Comment: @Rex: You're right. Sorry for not taking constructive criticism in the first place.